# How to change the "type" of a data row

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable that I am binding to a Gridview, in my c# code I periodically total a group of rows and add a new row with that group name and total. This isn't always at the end of the table. What I want to do is make that total row a distinct color. Some googling hinted that I can change the color based on the type of the data row in the RowDataBound method, but I couldn't find anything on how to change that type to something distinct first. Is this even the right/best way to do this? If so, how do I set the type of a Data Row.

My code behind is cluttered with other matters of selecting when to group, and I guess it isn't totally necessary to answer the question, but I'll post it anyway. This is the section where the new row is created and added: (which works fine)

```
  if (currentGroup != nextGroup)
                        {
                            DataRow newRow2 = dtYears.NewRow();
                            newRow2[0] = dr[0];
                            newRow2[1] = dr[1];
                            newRow2[2] = dr[2];
                            newRow2[3] = dr[3] + " TOTAL";
                            DataTable groupTotals = getGroupTableByYear(data);
                            DataRow[] foundRows = groupTotals.Select("GroupCode=" + "'" + currentgroup + "'");
                            newRow2[6] = foundRows.ElementAt(0).ItemArray[4];
                            newRow2[7] = foundRows.ElementAt(0).ItemArray[5];
                            newRow2[8] = foundRows.ElementAt(0).ItemArray[6]
                            dtYears.Rows.Add(newRow2);
                        }
```

Let me know if I need to explain any of that. Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: typos

**EDIT** Thanks to Yuriy, the answer is to create another column and make it invisible, that columns value can be used to set the color

Comment: Why can't u set color at the time of row creation?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. How would I do that? Is there a DataRow method for color?

Comment: Oh sorry, got confused with GridViewRow, thought you created those on the fly. In your case I'd suggest adding a a column to your DataTable with cell indicating row "type" that column will be invisible, not rendered into GridView, but used to determine row type and color needed for it.

Comment: Ah of course! I thought about adding a column for that, but I didn't want it to clog up the gridview. I can make it invisible by setting thatColumn.Visible = false, correct?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, set Visibility to false in code. Or, if your columns are not auto-generated (e.g. if you specify `<asp:BoundField...` in your grid markup) just don't include that particular column into markup